# Are there any mature distributed caching solutions available for C++ besides memcached?

Tags: c++, caching, distributed, cluster-computing

Most interested in peer-to-peer solutions - without central server. So, I imagine it like a library that brings to my application a functionality of transparent cache management with feature of remote instances synchronization. It should support cache record timeout and forcing invalidation.

UPDATE: If not completely peer-to-peer - at least with multiple servers feature.

Comment: Peer-to-peer caching would be possible but *really* inefficient. There would be lots of unneeded network traffic, data duplication, redundant responses, etc. Just look at Freenet.

Comment: @Zan That's exactly what DHTs (at least the ones using consistent hashing) were designed to do: efficiently retrieve data stored in a distributed fashion.

Comment: @Eugen: And DHT's are not efficient. They are good at what they do yes, but they cannot compete with a single server solution if the data load fits into a single server.

Comment: @Eugen: More info: My company recently evaluated Cassandra for key-value storage. Conclusion was that it takes 4 Cassandra systems to equal one Postgres DB server. After 4, of course Cassandra begins to take the lead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next best thing after Memcached is [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/):

(+) it supports more data types;

(+) has persistent storage;

(-/+) has a few [C++ clients](https://redis.io/clients#c--) that seem active (as of 09/2018) but none of them are "recommended".